# VS2010: Studio crashes when WPF designer opens any XAML control

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010

Every time I try to open XAML control, WPF-designer starts and at the same time as control representation is rendered Visual Studio crashes. I can observe WPF control representation and XAML tags for several seconds.

Windows 7, Visual Studio is launched as administrator.

There is error in event log:

Any ideas?

Application: devenv.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.AccessViolationException
Stack:
   at EnvDTE.CodeNamespace.get_Members()
   at MS.Internal.VSSymbols.SymbolProvider.AddNamespaces(EnvDTE.CodeNamespace, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2)
   at MS.Internal.VSSymbols.SymbolProvider.BuildNamespaces()
   at MS.Internal.VSSymbols.SymbolProvider.b__2(System.Object, System.EventArgs)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr, System.Object[], System.Object, Int32, Boolean, System.Object[] ByRef)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.AsyncProcessMessage(System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.IMessage, System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.IMessageSink)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.AgileAsyncWorkerItem.DoAsyncCall()
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.AgileAsyncWorkerItem.ThreadPoolCallBack(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
   at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()

Comment: Try openning the same project in the Expression Blend. VS might crash while parsing xaml, but blend will just report an error.

Comment: I have exactly the same probelm - it even happens when I create a brand new project, so it's not the XAML.

Answer (score 0):

The VS2010 XAML designer is very bad, it's better to completely turn it off and use Blend if you need to do some work with the designer.

Answer (score 0):

Installing this update might help: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=b3deb194-ca86-4fb6-a716-b67c2604a139&displaylang=en

The thread where I found this advice is: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/565048/visual-studio-2010-crashes-opening-wpf-user-control